# Grails mongo replica set configuration externalization

Tags: mongodb, grails

We have a web application which is developed by grails 2.4.3  and using MongoDB 3 replica set. The replica config mentioned in Config.groovy file. How can i read the replica config from external properties file (i.e. mongo.properties).
grails {
    mongo {
        replicaSet = [ "mongodev1.test.co:27017", "mongodev2.test.co:27017", "mongodev3.test.co:27017"]
    }
}

Can anybody guide me on this?

Comment: Answered here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/49878902/2360859 Please let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a blog on external config some time back : http://lalitagarw.blogspot.com/2014/03/grails-configuration-different-external.html

Define the below code in your main config. Once done you can place your external config file in the location : ${userHome}/.myConfig/${appName}-config.groovy

**appName** can be obtained by your application.properties file.

```
def customConfigLocations = []

if (new File("${userHome}/.myConfig/global-config.groovy").exists()) customConfigLocations.add("file:${userHome}/.myConfig/global-config.groovy")

if (new File("${userHome}/.myConfig/${appName}-config.groovy").exists()) customConfigLocations.add("file:${userHome}/.myConfig/${appName}-config.groovy")

if (customConfigLocations.empty) {
        println("No external configuration available......")
}else {
        grails.config.locations = customConfigLocations
        println("loading configuration from: :${grails.config.locations}")
}
```

Comment: I want to use .properties file not .groovy file.