# Mongodb repica set config in a property file

Tags: mongodb, grails, properties-file

We have a grails project in production. `Grails` version is `2.3.4`. We are using MongoDB for persistence.
Earlier, we had all the config hardcoded inside `DataSource.groovy`. The client demanded that the config be outside the `.war` file. So we moved it to a `.groovy` file. Everything was working fine, including the repicaSet config.
Then the client came up with another requirement. Since a groovy file can be used to give any programmable instruction, it can be misused by a person whose job is just to update a property file. So they want all the config in a `.properties` file.

here is the contents of my `.properties` file

```
grails.mongo.host=10.3.253.201
grails.mongo.port=27017
grails.mongo.databaseName=testDb
grails.mongo.username=mongouser
grails.mongo.password=mongouser
```

Where can I give the details of replicaSet? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to answer this question in case someone else is facing the same isssue.

```
grails.mongo.uri=mongodb://10.3.253.201,10.3.253.202,10.3.253.203/test
grails.mongo.host=10.3.253.201
grails.mongo.port=27017
grails.mongo.databaseName=test
grails.mongo.username=mongouser
grails.mongo.password=mongouser
```

This is the content of my config.properties file and it started working for me.

```
201 was the primary node and the other two were backup in my cluster.
```

Regards.